# Traefik handling of malformed GET packet

Tags: traefik

I am trying to forward traffic through Traefik, some of which comes from a device which has a poorly implemented http client in it. The client makes a request which contains TWO SPACES after the get. So it will make a request like "`GET  / HTTP/1.0`" and Traefik appears to ignore the request. Is there a way to support an additional protocol via a plugin or some configuration to allow a malformed http packet through? I was considering perhaps using a TCP entry point and then crafting middleware to handle the malformed packet, but was unsure if there was some way of handling it at the ingest stage.
Thanks!